# How to ignore previous AJAX data return?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

I wonder what a good way is to ignore earlier but delayed AJAX data return, when a newer AJAX call should be taken care of instead?

For example, if the first data fetch that started at 12:01:33 is delayed and returns at 12:01;39, and the second data fetch that started at 12:01:36 actually came back first, at 12:01:38.  So the data returned at 12:01:39 should not be honored and should not be displayed onto the webpage and "cover up" the result of the second data fetch.

In some case, we might disable the Search or Submit button so that the user cannot click on the button again, but what about if there is a text input box, and the user typed "React" and press Enter, but he changed his mind and added "Redux" to the search box and pressed Enter again, and results returned by the "React" search should then be ignored (for both of the cases if this first AJAX returns either before or after the second AJAX), and only results returned by "React Redux" should be taken care of, to populate into the search result area down below.

In my past jobs, it seems that nobody actually took care of things like this.  I can think of one way, which is:

```
let fetchTimeStampToHonor;

function getData() {
  let currentFetchTimestamp = Date.now();
  fetchTimeStampToHonor = currentFetchTimestamp;

  fetch("...")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => { 
      if (currentFetchTimestamp === fetchTimeStampToHonor) {  // honor it

      }
    });
}
```

so that if there is a newer call to `getData()`, then `fetchTimeStampToHonor` will get updated to the newest `currentFetchTimestamp`.  The function passed to `then` is a closure and is able to access the local `currentFetchTimestamp`, and can be compared with `fetchTimeStampToHonor`.  But the code above involves a global variable, which I can hide if I use a function to return `getData()`, and this way, I can hide `fetchTimeStampToHonor` inside of local scope and make it private. (but I think if this is inside of a module, it is private to the module and isn't such a big problem).  Or it might be able to be made into some state if it is in ReactJS.

But are there some other better solutions?

Comment: What if you queue the requests and wait for earlier request to finish with a response if both requests are for the same URL before sending the new/later request?

Comment: if you queue them?  So what if the first request got stuck and it is not returning for 6 seconds... then the newer request cannot go through or get processed but have to keep waiting?

Comment: Add the server timestamp to the resultset and store this timestamp on the client. When the data arrives, compare the timestamp with the one you have on the client.

Comment: but then you have to change the server too?  So then this solution will depend on how the server behaves?

Comment: There's also a way to cancel a pending fetch request as described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)

Comment: @Christian to outright cancel it? Maybe that's a good solution too... it helps not needing to go through `res.json()` and having `data`... both waste processing time and computer memory

Answer (score 1):

You could produce a local cache of results. Use the search term as the key, then only show the relevant results. The code below is far from optimised and I would NOT use it as is, but I hope it illustrates the point.

I've used react in the example as it provides an easy way to show stateful changes but this concept could be done with raw JS as well.

```
const App = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
  const [dataCache, setDataCache] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`search?term=${searchTerm}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setDataCache((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [searchTerm]: data,
      }))
    })
  }, [searchTerm])

  return (
    <>
      <input type="search" onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
      <Results data={dataCache[searchTerm]} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: if you use this dataCache, how do you prevent the scenario that the search results for "React Redux" comes back first, and then 2 seconds later, the results for "React" come back and show on the screen, but these are not the results we want any more

Comment: Let's say that all the requests have now come back. Cache results looks like `{ 'React Redux': {...}, React: {...} }`. The search term will always be what the user typed most recently, in this case "React Redux". When we do the lookup `dataCache[searchTerm]` it equates to `dataCache['React Redux']`. Hope that helps

Comment: oh I see what you mean... that'd help.  Originally, the intention was to ignore earlier AJAX requests... such as when we fetch stock price data at 12:03;33 and then it didn't come back yet and the user fetches the price at 12:03:38 again... so in this case it is more about ignore the previous fetch as opposed to caching all the results

Comment: For data like stocks that needs to be kept up-to-date it's probably better to use some variation on websockets, socket.io for example

Comment: or I mean here is like a "Refresh" button to fetch the data once